# Failed to start SSH Agent: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot parse ssh-agent output: '' - TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, ssh-agent

System configs:
TeamCity Master: Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
TeamCity Agent: Windows Server 2022 Datacenter
Infrastructure is in AWS with the correct security groups and open ports needed (9090, 22, 443, etc)

I keep getting this error. I have checked that the ssh-agent is in the path. Keys  are added to Teamcity master (private) and GitHub (public key, clone is successful). Windows firewall is also open for port exceptions.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious solution to this is to make TeamCity use the `ssh-agent`, which comes with *Git for Windows*. TeamCity [claims](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/2017.1/ssh-agent.html#agent-setup) to be compatible with ssh agent implementations of CygWin and MinGW too.

First, on the TeamCity agent add the path to Git's `ssh-agent.exe` to the `PATH` environment variable and make sure that it will be found **before** Windows' version of it.
It should look like: `PATH=C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;...` You will need to restart the agent to have this take effect.

Second, it might be necessary to also make sure that Git uses the same OpenSSH implementation. To do so set the `GIT_SSH` environment variable. It should look like e.g.: `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe` (see the [Git docs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables))

Answer (score 0):

Seems like TeamCity is incompatible with Windows OpenSSH variant. I suggest you to uninstall it (via powershell or windows features) and install git for windows instead which in bundled with all ssh tools.

Comment: I have both varients of OpenSSH agent on the machine (win & git). Both are in path

Comment: You could try to uninstall windows variant